# I'm having a hard time calculating a percentage from a column with an alias

Tags: sql

I am using a subquery to calculate percentages on a column with an alias, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why the sum() function won't sum up the values in the column. It just divides the numbers by themselves and multiplies times 100, so effectively, 100 for every total. EDIT: I had to cut the query before my from and properly bracketed group by clauses. The query works, but returns 100 for all percentages.

```
Select A.[DataCollection Period Report Year], A.[Section Name], A.[Form Name], A.Amount, 
(A.Amount / sum(A.Amount)) * 100 as Percentage
from
(
Select distinct [DataCollection Period Report Year],
      RFD.[Section Name],   
      RFD.[Form Name],
      sum(cast(RFD.Answer as float)) as Amount        `
```

Comment: Your query is broken, there are not enough closing ')' and there's a lost `

Comment: I had to cut my query off, but there is a 'From' as well as two 'Group by' clauses properly bracketed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a group by statement in your sub query and initial query. Also your sub query is missing a FROM statement. You also need to keep your aliases consistent.

```
     SELECT A."DataCollection Period Report Year",
    A."Section Name",
    A."Form Name",
    A.Answer,
    (A.Answer / sum(temp.Amount)) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM myTable A
join (
SELECT DISTINCT RFD."DataCollection Period Report Year",
sum(cast(RFD.Answer AS FLOAT)) AS Amount
FROM myTable RFD
group by 
"DataCollection Period Report Year"
) temp
GROUP BY 
A."DataCollection Period Report Year",
    A."Section Name",
    A."Form Name",
    A.Answer
```

Comment: I cut the script because of confidentiality issues, but I do have the from as well as group by clauses and I'm getting a response, it's just 100 all the time.

Comment: I think I know the issue, is this for 1 year or multiple years per "Data Collection Period Report Year"? I will update the code pending your response.

Comment: It's just one year

Comment: I just updated the answer, try that I think that is what you are trying to do. You'll need to create a join from the from, to the nested statement.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! I will try this